# NavigationController Skip View

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to skip a view in a Navigation Controller? My structure is as follows:

```
**Main Screen Navigation Controller**
-Main Screen View

**Options Navigation Controller (Modal transition from Main Screen View)**
-Options Screen View
--Sub Options Screen View(Push from Options View)
```

On the first load of the application, I want to present a "Welcome" `UIAlertView` that will present the "Sub Options" screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to build your navigation stack programmatically and then modally display the `UINavigationController`. Use the `viewControllers` property. The last view controller in the passed in array will become the top view controller.

```
OptionsViewController *ovc = [[OptionsViewController alloc] init];
SubOptionsViewController *sovc = [[SubOptionsViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
nav.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ovc, sovc, nil];
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you read the documentation for [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you'll see there's a method called [`setViewControllers:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW20) that you can use to explicitly set the entire stack of view controllers at once.

Comment: I have read this but I really don't understand how setting the view controllers helps me. I set them via IB. What am I missing here?

Comment: Navigation controllers work as a stack.  You start off with the root view controller.  When you want to navigate to a particular view controller, it gets pushed onto the stack.  When you want to come back out, you pop the current view controller off the stack and the previous one is underneath.  In your case, you want to set your navigation controller so you are several levels deep.  To do this, you can set the entire stack at once.

Comment: For more information, see [the section on navigation controllers in the View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1).